# If $f: X \to Y$ is a continuous surjection (onto), then a map $g: Y \to Z$ is open if $g \circ f : X \to Z$ is open.

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

If $f: X \to Y$ is a continuous surjection (onto), then a map $g: Y \to Z$ is open if $g \circ f : X \to Z$ is open.

Since $g \circ f $ is open so image of every open set is open. Let $A$ be an open set in $X$. So $(g \circ f )(A)$ is open in $Z$. Thus to show that $g$ is open we have to show that  $f(A)$ is open. But from definition of continuity of $f$ given an open set $V$ containing $f(x)$ in $Y$, we can find an open set $U$ containing $x$ such that $f(U) \subset V$.

Then how will I use the condition that $f$ is onto to reach that given an open set $A$ in $X$ we get an open set $f(A)$ in Y??

Answer (score 2):

Wait, what you should be showing is that for every $A$ open in $\color{red}{Y}$, $g(A)$ is open in $\color{red}{Z}$. Let $A$ be an open subset of $Y$. Since $f$ is surjective, $A = f(f^{-1}(A))$. Hence $g(A) = (g\circ f)(f^{-1}(A))$. Since $A$ is open and $f$ is continuous, $f^{-1}(A)$ is open. So since $g\circ f$ is open, so is $(g\circ f)(f^{-1}(A))$, i.e., $g(A)$. Hence, $g$ is open.